# C dynamically allocate struct type

Tags: c, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a struct which is defined as following

```
typedef struct{
    int year;
    char* name;
    int id;
}person;
```

How do I dynamically allocate person object and insert my data into it?
My data is shown as below

```
    int personYear = 20;
    int personId = 12345678;
    char* personName = "firstname lastname";
```

I know that for declaration I can do

```
person* p = (person*) malloc(sizeof(person));
p->year = personYear;
p->id = personId;
```

But after that, how do I do insertion for `char* person?`
Do I have to reallocate the space to hold memory space?

```
 // my thought 
  p->name = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char));
  int counter = 0;
  while (*personName != '\0')
  {
      counter++;
      name = (char*) realloc (name, counter+1) // hold 1 more byte 
      *(name+counter) = '\0'; //make sure intialize the value 
      *(name+counter-1) = *personName;
      personName++;
  }
 //what's next?
```

What's really confusing is since struct has memor alignment in C, and at runtime, our program doesn't know how many bytes that person->name will hold, do we need to keep reallocating memory space for struct itself? what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Step back; take a deep breath; *what do you actually want the computer to do*? `person->name` is a pointer. That means it contains the address of (i.e. it points to) something else. What would you like it to point to?

Comment: Unrelated: Instead of `person* p = (person*) malloc(sizeof(person));` you can do `person* p = malloc(sizeof *p);` - You don't need to cast and taking the `sizeof` the dereferenced pointer makes it a little clearer (in many peoples opinion).

Comment: You do not need to realloc space for the string one character at a time. Just malloc the length of the string plus 1: `p->name = malloc(strlen(personName) + 1);` `strcpy(p->name, personName);`. (Note 1: `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition, so no need to multiply `(strlen(personName) + 1)` by `sizeof(char)` in the above. Note 2: There is no need to type cast the return value of `malloc()` to another pointer type.) Some library implementations have a `strdup()` function (not part of the C17 standard) to do the above in one: `p->name = strdup(personName);`.

Comment: I suggest using `strdup()`.

Answer (score 1):

One approach to the problem is using a flexible struct member. It works by placing an array just after a struct. In this case it would be an array of `char` with the name string.

```
typedef struct {
    int year;
    int id;
    char name[]; // flexible member
}person;
```

When allocating `struct person` just add extra `strlen(name) + 1` bytes, and copy the `name` there.

```
person* make_person(int year, int id, char *name) {
  person *p = malloc(sizeof *p + strlen(name) + 1);
  if (!p) return NULL; // out of memory
  p->id = id;
  p->year = year;
  strcpy(p->name, name);
  return p;
}
```

Comment: Not a very useful approach as it makes it a lot harder if you ever want to increase the size of the string as `realloc` can relocate the memory if there isn't space to increase it

Comment: <string.h> is prohibited and there is no way to know how many char will be in member names at compile time

Comment: @randomNameGenerator, `<string.h>` is prohibited?! Is it some kind of sadistic homework then?

Comment: @randomNameGenerator, the only way is to implement `strlen()` yourself. It is more or less already realized by the loop from the question: `int counter = 0;
  while (*personName != '\0')
  {
      counter++; ... ;  personName++;
  }`

Comment: yeah, it is a programming hw for pointers only LOL, so basically I have to implement this by using pointer

Comment: thats why i didnt use memset(), etc

Comment: I mean this string.h is not allowed to use, my approach would work or no?

Comment: @randomNameGenerator, your approach should work though it is very inefficient. It is idiomatic for C to first count the number of character, then allocate memory and copy the string.

Comment: It worked, but pointer arithmetic is so inefficient comes to string copying LOL